# Python - any statement that isn't accepted

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and decided to make a little dice game. It functions 100% as intended, just want to make some small changes to make it more polished up, such as not just ending if you input something that isn't supported.

```
if answer == 'y':
dice = raw_input('What sorta dice? (D4, D6, D12, D20)')
--if dice = ANYTHING THAT ISN'T A DICE
    dice = raw_input('I don't have that, try again!')--

else:
if answer == 'n':
    print 'Alright, come back anytime!'
    exit()
```

I just can't find an answer to the if dice = problem, I've googled for about an hour and chances are I just don't know the right terminology to ask the question properly. I basically want it to state something along the lines of "nope thats not right" then loop back up to "what sorta dice"

Cheers for any input guys.

Comment: Do you know how to figure out if it's the *right* input?

Comment: `if dice not in ['D4', 'D6', 'D12', 'D20']`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
if dice not in ('D4', 'D6', 'D12', 'D20'):
    ...
```

and if you want to make sure things like `'d4'` also get accepted:

```
if dice.upper() not in ('D4', 'D6', 'D12', 'D20'):
    ...
```

and - as mentioned by [Delgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291710/delgan) - comparing to a `set` not a `tuple` is faster even for only 4 elements (and scales way better the higher the number of elements is)

```
if dice.upper() not in {'D4', 'D6', 'D12', 'D20'}:
    ...
```

Comment: Best practice is to use a set: `in {'D4', 'D6', 'D12', 'D20'}` as look-up time is O(1).

Comment: @Delgan if you mean 'best in terms of speed': not sure if `set` is quicker for 4 elements than `tuple`. but in general i agree - it *scales* better.

Comment: Yes, I mean it is better to stay with sets in the general cases, just for consistency. Even for 4 elements, [it is actually faster](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/51/1482573733-screenshot.png).

Comment: @Delgan: ha, thanks for the benchmark. will try to remember that. updated the (closed) question.